# Arduino-compatible Bluetooth classic module to use in a product

Tags: bluetooth, library, hc-05

I've been designing a product for some time using arduino language, but on our own hardware. Recently a need arose to add some Bluetooth capability to our product. We decided to use BT classic instead of BLE, because not every phone has BLE capability yet. Of course immediately I went to check [HC-05](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01G9KSAF6) modules and their cousins. The issue is I believe they are a chinese product and have no FCC certification and I can't buy them from any reputable source (digikey,mouser,farnell etc.).

Seeing that this is an issue for a product I went and checked the mentioned suppliers to see what they offer. The thing is though, I'd like to stay in the arduino environment so I'm looking for a module that has some support from the arduino side.

I found [this](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Cypress-Semiconductor/CYBT-213043-02?qs=sGAEpiMZZMu3sxpa5v1qrgkV%252BmLWY283etI2l9FHofA%3D) module from Cypress, that has [this](https://www.mouser.com/new/cypress-semiconductor/cypress-cybt-213043-eval-board/) "arduino-compatible" code. However when a tried to find any library that I could use to program this board using arduino environment on Cypress's site I only found mentions of their own SDK.

Thus comes the question: are there any FCC compliant bluetooth modules that have an easy to use arduino library available?

Comment: You've got the same compatibility issue whether you choose BLE or BT-2. Not every phone has BT-2 either: iPhones have had BLE (only) for some time.

Comment: Hmm didn't know that. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: You should choose chip that support at least bluetooth 4.0 or above (i.e. BLE capable) as this is most of the phones or other products supporting now. BT2.0 probably only supported by products that are more than 10 years old.

Comment: There are plenty of FCC pre-certified modules to choose from, look at their FCC certified ID which is usually available on the RF shield cover of the module.